# how to send bulk whatsapp message one time and fastly in excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba, whatsapp

I'm trying to send bulk WhatsApp messages via excel macro. But If I send 1000 messages it is taking a very long time. And I cannot send all messages at one time. How can I do? Is it possible? Also, WhatsApp is working top most If I click another thing on my computer WhatsApp message is not sending. How can I fix these problems:
Note: I'm using the WhatsApp desktop application.
It is part of my code I'm doing with for loop:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 'Create object IE
IE.navigate "whatsapp://send?phone=" & phone & "&text=Dear " & Sheet1.Cells(rowcount, 1) & vbLf & " " & mesaj 'Send message "something" to this phone (Brazil)
Application.Wait Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2) 'ok just one wait and sendkeys
   
If pic <> "" Then
    Call SendKeys("^v")
    Application.Wait Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
End If
SendKeys "~"
'IE.Quit 'The navigate already kills the IE

Set IE = Nothing 'Clear the object
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to the search box and enter the contact by phone number, Do not use the URL  `send?phone=" & phone & "&text=`

```
Dim phone as long
Dim message as string
Dim i as long
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 'Create object IE
    IE.navigate "https://web.whatsapp.com/"
Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:15")) 
for i= 1 to 5
    phone= cells(i,"A")
    message= cells(i,"B")
    SendKeys("{TAB}", True)
    SendKeys("{TAB}", True)
    SendKeys(phone, True)
    SendKeys("~", True)
    SendKeys(message, True)
    SendKeys("~", True)
    Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:03")) 
Next
```

Please accept as answered.

Comment: I cant accept as answer sorry. Because I have to send bulk and automatically message. Your method everytime sending for one message. It is not answer for me

Comment: Does whatsapp web work in Internet Explorer?

Comment: Loop to send multipule messages without set ie= nothing

Comment: hi @NoamBrand how can I send multiple message with loop with your way ? Please improve your answer code

Comment: also how to set phone and message with your code ? you are calling only web.whatsap

Comment: Check out the improvement

Answer (score 0):

You can only send a single message with group send to send to all at once. I have an exemplary practice too, you can check it if you want. Whatsapp sends messages in 3 to 6 seconds with the desktop.
[Case study link](https://excel-studio.blogspot.com/2019/06/excelden-whatsappla-resim-ve-yaz.html)